# Unity High Score Not Updating and only keeps same value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the Script where I calculate and compare scores.

```
void Start()
{
    theScore = this;
    score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("GameScore", 0);
    highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("NewHighScore", 0);
}

void Update () 
{
    PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");

    score += Time.deltaTime;

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Score", (int)score *100);
}

public void PowerUpScore(int pwrUps)
{
    score += pwrUps;
}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10,10, 100, 30), "Score: " + (int)(score*100));
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10,20, 100, 30), "High Score: " + (int)(highScore));
    //GUI.Label(new Rect(10,20, 100, 30), "Ammo Left: " + (int)(ammo + 5));
}

public void CheckScore()
{

    if (score > highScore) 
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("NewHighScore", (int)score*100);
    }
}
```

They are then meant to be compared in here in `Update` but it doesn't seem to be working

```
void Start()
{
    playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
}

void Update()
{
    Vector3 playerPos = playerTransform.position;
    yPosition = playerTransform.position.y;

    if(yPosition<-9f)
    {   
        Scoring.theScore.CheckScore();
        Application.LoadLevel(2);           
    }
}
```

If anyone had any ideas they'd be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that CheckScore() only updates PlayerPrefs, but not the highScore value.  Try this:

```
public void CheckScore()
{

    if (score > highScore) 
    {
        highScore = score;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("NewHighScore", (int)score*100);
    }
}
```